# Node.js: handling file uploads, 'data' event never called

Tags: file, node.js, file-upload, upload

A trivial case describing the problem... Client side (using HTML5 file API and XMLHttpRequest2):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest ()
xhr.open ('POST', '/upload', true)
xhr.send (file) /* sends as plain binary blob, no multipart/form-data */
```

Server side:

```
var size = 0
request.setEncoding ('binary')
request.on ('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log ('Received ' + (size += chunk.length) / (1024.0 * 1024.0) + ' Mb')
})
request.on ('end', function (chunk) {
    console.log ('Done')
})
```

The problem is that 'data' event is either never get called, or starts picking up wrong parts of file (not from beginning). It seems like actual data chunks start arriving before 'data' event binding occurs.

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what caused the problem, it turned out my data-receiving code was executing inside an asynchronous callback deep inside application logic.

The problem is solved by pausing request at the beginning of the request handler with request.pause(), and resuming it later after it reaches through layers of app logic, after the 'data' and the 'end' events are bound.